# Missing visual editor after placing a redirect rule into the .htaccess file

Tags: htaccess, visual-editor

My blog ([blog.mywebroom.com](http://blog.mywebroom.com)) isn't showing the visual editor whenever I try to edit or add a new post. I tried a whole host of solutions, except I couldn't figure it out. The editor disappeared about a week ago after I placed a redirect url into the .htaccess file.
I've tried contacting my host provider who could provide no solution and I've scoured the forums for an answer. Can anyone provide a solution?

I added these rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?blog\.mywebroom\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.mywebroom.com/blog%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Post the redirect rule you added that you think is causing the problem. Also, check for the console to see if there are any JS errors. If there are, post those here too.

Comment: I added in the rules, but I haven't received any JS errors

Comment: Have you disabled all plugins and used a default theme (one of the Twenty's) to isolate the issue and rule out a plugin issue?